# If both are ok, which one is more idiomatic: "to get a diagnosis" or "to have a diagnosis"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrases, idiomatic-language

**"to get a diagnosis"**

**"to have a diagnosis"?**

I have seen both are used when I did a search on google, but "to get a diagnosis" seems far more common than "have a diagnosis" according to google search results.

Which one do you think is more idiomatic?

Comment: Why do you think it's any different than the normal difference between "have" and "get"?

Comment: Because I thought that you can't have a diagnosis. Maybe because of my native language, I thought that having a diagnosis might be wrong, because a diagnosis is something that should be provided/given/granted by a doctor. I thought one can not have it as if they can have some tea which you can have yourself. It sounded unusual to me.

Comment: In that case, yes, "diagnosis" follows the normal meanings of "get" and "have", and it's perfectly natural to use either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"to get a diagnosis"* implies the action of getting the diagnosis.

*"to have a diagnosis"* implies that fact that one has been obtained.

e.g.

*"Now that the test are complete I finally have a diagnosis"*

versus

*"My stomach has been hurting for weeks, I'll go to the doctor and get a diagnosis."*

note that 'have got' has the same sense as 'have'.

Answer (score 2):

Not according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=get+a+diagnosis%2C+have+a+diagnosis&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20diagnosis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20diagnosis%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cget%20a%20diagnosis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20diagnosis%3B%2Cc0)!

If you *get* a diagnosis, you obtain one. If you *have* one, you have already obtained it.